# Код для нахождения суммы n-го количества факториалов

Tags: c++

Нужен код для нахождения суммы n-го количества факториалов с использованием цикла for или while.

Comment: Нужен - напишите. Многие на этом сайте обычно так и делают. Отличное решение  рекомендую.

Comment: @Эникейщик , Готово!

Comment: @Eto_sova Готово, это хорошо. Но все же в следующий раз формулируйте вопрос более внятно. Посчитать сумму факториалов- понято, а вот то, что это должны были быть факториалы чисел от 1 до n Вы забыли упомянуть

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "math.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a, b = 1, c = 0;
    cin >> a;

    for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
    {
        b *= i;
        c += b;
    }
    cout << b << endl; 
    cout << c << endl;

}
```

Comment: Сам спросил - сам ответил. - Цицерон